# Stop Python from trowing KeyError exceptions

Tags: python, python-2.7

I get an error while running my script and I know it is there, But I don't want Python to print the error. The error (it is a KeyError) is in a if statement. Is there a way to stop the if statement from printing error messages?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Comment: If you only want not to display the error, just redirect the stderr stream do /dev/null if you have a Unix-like system. It can also be done under Windows, but it needs a wrapper program to do the redirection (to nul:) before launching Python. But beware, an uncatched KeyError will abort the script ...

Comment: _Fixing_ the problem is almost always better than merely hiding it.  It would help if we could see the code that's producing the `KeyError`.  If it's caused by something like `some_dict[bogus_key]`, you can instead use the [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method with a default.

Answer (score -2):

Try this.

```
while True:
     try:
         x = int(raw_input("Please enter a number: "))
         break
     except ValueError:
         print "Oops!  That was no valid number.  Try again..."
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?